# Why is my multiprocessing code leaking?

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I have created a flow of execution which spawns several Processes and then on those spawns several Threads.

I thought some issues could be:

- I am not joining the queue correctly. I join once in the process to get the results from the thread and then once outside to get the processes. However I don't join the sub-process.
- I am not using `process.daemon = True`
- I am missing a break somewhere, etc.

However, I notice that as I go through the loop some processes remain and do not close and can't seem to figure out why.

First I create two queues to hold my request-urls and then the response from them. Then, I start my processes, which in turn establish a `urllib3.HTTPConnectionPool` and then create threads (using that thread-safe connection pool).

The issue is that some of the processes don't fully close and I can't figure out why.

```
from threading import Thread
from urllib3 import HTTPConnectionPool
from multiprocessing import Process, cpu_count, Queue, JoinableQueue, Event


class Consumer(Thread):
    def __init__(self, qin, qout, conn_pool):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.__qin = qin
        self.__qout = qout
        self.__connpool = conn_pool

    def run(self):
        # Close once queue empty (otherwise process will linger)
        while not self.__qin.empty():
            msg = self.__qin.get()
            ul, qid = msg
            try:
                response = self.__connpool.request('GET', ul)
                s = float(response.status)
                if s == 200:
                    json_geocode = json.loads(response.data.decode('utf-8'))
                    tot_time_s = json_geocode['paths'][0]['time']
                    tot_dist_m = json_geocode['paths'][0]['distance']
                    out = [qid, s, tot_time_s, tot_dist_m]
                elif s == 400:
                    #print("Done but no route for row: ", qid)
                    out = [qid, 999, 0, 0]
                else:
                    print("Done but unknown error for: ", s)
                    out = [qid, 999, 0, 0]
            except Exception as err:
                print(err)
                out = [qid, 999, 0, 0]
            #print(out)
            self.__qout.put(out)
            self.__qin.task_done()
            return


class Worker(Process):
    def __init__(self, qin, qout, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Worker, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._qin = qin
        self._qout = qout
        self.exit = Event()

    def run(self):
        # Create thread-safe connection pool
        concurrent = 10
        with HTTPConnectionPool(host=ghost, port=gport, maxsize=concurrent) as conn_pool:
            num_threads = concurrent
            # Start threads (concurrent) per process
            for _ in range(num_threads):
                Consumer(self._qin, self._qout, conn_pool).start()
            # Block until all urls in self._qin are processed
            self._qin.join()
        return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for _ in range(100):
        # Fill queue input
        qin = JoinableQueue()
        for url_q in url_routes:
            qin.put(url_q) 
        # Queue to collect output
        qout = Queue()
        # Start cpu_count number of processes (which will launch threads and sessions)
        for __ in range(cpu_count())
            Worker(qin, qout).start()
        # Block until all urls in qin are processed
        qin.join()
        # Fill routes
        calc_routes = []
        while not qout.empty():
            calc_routes.append(qout.get())
```

Comment: Would be helpful for me to get a comment behind a down-vote so that I know what to improve in the post. However, I have added a bit more explanation

Comment: I wonder why are you using list comprehensions instead of ordinary `for` loops: `[qin.put(url_q) for url_q in url_routes]`?

Comment: I just wanted to fit one line - is it bad practice?

Comment: I don't think that it's so bad, but such expressions create lists of whatever, for example, `qin.put` returns. They're simply used for different purposes.

Comment: @ForceBru Yes, I see - you're right it looks weird when I don't use them to create a list. I will update the code. Any chance that is somehow interfering with this?

Comment: I don't think so. It's just a (slightly incorrect) usage of list comprehensions. BTW, there are some things I don't quite understand in your code: why are you using _both_ `multiprocessing` and `threading`? They're both designed to run tasks in parallel, so perhaps it would be better to use only one of them? Moreover, you're declaring `class Consumer` right in the `run` function which makes you do a lot of indentation that may cause poor readability. The same thing as with the list comprehensions: slightly incorrect usage of classes.

Comment: @ForceBru Initially I found that using multi-threading to send off multiple requests at once and then running that n times (at once) on n processes gave me the highest requests-per-second rate. For example if I just use multi-threading I am limited by GIL and if I just use multi-processing I submit a maximum of (cpu_count) requests each time. I have incorporated your style suggestions into my editing post. Thanks!